# SSO and ServletRequest.login() and ServletRequest.logout() not working in Glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, single-sign-on

// I'll try to improve the question a bit to see if I can get help.

We have a set of applications in our glassfish server, and we'd like to use SSO across them. So, we came up with a "authentication" web application, which simply contains the form to authenticate users. This user is then routed by this application to the whichever application he wants to acess.

The problem is that, when using the FORM authentication method and the programmatic login through ServletRequest.login(), the SSO cookie **is not created**. Only through BASIC authentication or through j_security_check we are able to see the SSO session cookie being created.

Similarly, the ServletRequest.logout() method is also unable to log the user off the SSO session, leading to nasty security bugs.

I'd like to know whether the approach using programmatic login/logout and SSO does not work at all (and thus, we're doing it wrong); or, if we're missing something altogether about SSO and security in Glassfish.

Comment: As a side note, the request.logout() also does not invalidate the SSO cookie!

Comment: This fact is even mentioned in their documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7695/beacm/index.html `The programmatic login state does not necessarily persist in sessions or participate in single sign-on.`

Answer (score 1):

Guess I've found the reason: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18356

The bug is open, likely to make it into the new version... but voting it up would help make it happen. If you came across this question with the same problem, please help voting for it!